# Filter posts by multiple taxonomies using checkbox and select

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Hey so I'll try to make this quick. I'm trying to filter my custom post type(attractions) with two different taxonomies(city and category) in a front end form using a select dropdown and checkboxes. Currently, my select filter works but my checkbox filters do not work on their own and don't work along with the select dropdown.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcs81.png)

I tried to use this article to help me out: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html

Frontend PHP Form

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
<!--            Cities select filter -->
        <?php
    if( $terms = get_terms( 'city', 'orderby=name' ) ) : // to make it simple I use default categories
        echo '<select value ="" name="cityfilter"><option>Select City...</option>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) :
            echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>'; // ID of the category as the value of an option
        endforeach;
        echo '</select>';
    endif;?>
<!--        Categories filter -->
        <div class="categories-list">
        <?php 
          $categories = get_categories(); 
          foreach ($categories as $category) {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="categoryfilter" value="'.$category->cat_ID.'"> '.$category->name.'<br />';
          }
        ?>
        </div>

            <button class="itenerary-filter">Apply filter</button>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">

    </form>
```

Functions.php Query

```
function misha_filter_function(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
        'order' => $_POST['date'] // ASC или DESC
    );
    $relation = 'OR';
    if($_POST['categoryfilter'] == 'on' && isset( $_POST['cityfilter'] )) {
        $relation = 'AND';
    }
    if( isset( $_POST['cityfilter'] ) ||  (isset( $_POST['categoryfilter']) && $_POST['categoryfilter'] == 'on') )
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            'relation' => $relation, 
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'city',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['cityfilter']
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter'],
            ),
        );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            get_template_part('template_parts/loop_content','attractions');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    die();
}


add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');
```

Javascript

```
$('#filter').submit(function(){
        var filter = $('#filter');
        $.ajax({
            url:filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(), // form data
            type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                filter.find('button').text('Processing...'); // changing the button label
            },
            success:function(data) {
                filter.find('button').text('Apply filter'); // changing the button label back
                $('#external-events-listing').html(data); // insert data
                $('#external-events-listing .feature-attraction').addClass('feature-attraction_itenerary ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle').removeClass('feature-attraction');
                $('.feature-attraction_itenerary .wrapper').addClass('wrapper_itenerary').removeClass('wrapper');
                $('#external-events .feature-attraction_itenerary').each(function() {
                        // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                        $(this).data('event', {
                            title: $.trim($(this).text()),
                            // use the element's text as the event title
                            stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                        });
                        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                        $(this).draggable({
                            zIndex: 999,
                            revert: true,
                            // will cause the event to go back to its
                            revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
                        });
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:**

So I var_dump($args); as suggested. I got this array by selecting an option from my drop down and selecting a checkbox. The thing is, relation should not be 'relation' => 'OR' when selecting both it should be 'AND'. What I want to be able to do is when both filters are selected 'OR' should be 'AND'. Is there anyway to do so?

```
array (size=3)
  'orderby' => string 'date' (length=4)
  'order' => null
  'tax_query' => 
    array (size=3)
      'relation' => string 'OR' (length=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'taxonomy' => string 'city' (length=4)
          'field' => string 'id' (length=2)
          'terms' => string '6' (length=1)
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'taxonomy' => string 'category' (length=8)
          'field' => string 'id' (length=2)
          'terms' => string '7' (length=1)
```

Comment: You code needs to be debugged. As it is too long, it is not easy to detect what the wrong is there. Just debug it and make some clarifications. F.e.  var_dump($args); before the line $query = new WP_Query( $args ); - and paste output data to your question

Comment: I added the data that's output...it looks like my relation is not changing from 'OR' to 'AND' when my checkbox is clicked. Is there anyway I can fix that?

Comment: ok i am adding the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code.
categoryfilter doesn't get the value "on" - so you should remove it from if condition.

Here is it:

```
function misha_filter_function(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date', // we will sort posts by date
        'order' => $_POST['date'] // ASC или DESC
    );
    $relation = 'OR';
    if(!empty($_POST['categoryfilter']) && isset( $_POST['cityfilter'] )) {
        $relation = 'AND';
    }
    if( isset( $_POST['cityfilter'] ) ||  !empty( $_POST['categoryfilter']) )
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            'relation' => $relation, 
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'city',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['cityfilter']
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter'],
            ),
        );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
            get_template_part('template_parts/loop_content','attractions');
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    die();
}


add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');
```

Comment: This is really close to what I need. The only thing is if two checkbox's are selected on their own (So in my example restauraunts and Tours & Attractions) then only one of those categories is shown. Is there anyway that could be implemented?

Comment: Try replace name="categoryfilter" with name="categoryfilter[]" in your HTML code.